# How to parse an audio file and download it by jsoup , Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup, html-parsing

[Website HTML Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvQJm.png)

```
Elements elementsVoice = document.select("span[class='daud']>audio");
```

I want to download the audio files in the photo from the link.But when I write the code, no data is coming.
Can I download these files using jsoup, can you help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The code gets all audio file sources.

```
Elements h2 = document.select("source[type='audio/mpeg']");
```

The code parses all audio files .

```
String[] splitUrl = (h2.toString()).split("src=");
```

The codes get the address of the exact audio file.

```
mp3Url = ((splitUrl[1]).replace(">",""));
String arg = (mp3Url.replace("\"","")).replace("<source type=audio/mpeg","");
```

The codes combine the Audio Url to download.

```
URL url1;
URL reconUrl1 = null;
try {
    url1 = new URL(strUrl1);
    reconUrl1 = new URL(url1,arg);     
    }

catch (MalformedURLException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The codes combine the Audio Url to download.

```
try {
    URLConnection conn = new URL(reconUrl1.toString()).openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    String urlEnd = (getExternalFilesDir + name + "_voice.mp3");
    OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File(urlEnd));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}

catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```